# Error: Property timer doesn't exist on type typeof Observable

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable

The code is below

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: 'Ticks (every second) : {{ticks}}'
})
export class AppComponent {
   ticks =0;

   click(){
      let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
      timer.subscribe(t=>this.ticks = t);
   }
}
```

But i am getting an error. The error is in the following line:

```
let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
```

The definition of error is "property timer doesn't exist on type typeof Observable"
Why am I getting error like that?
What do you think?

Comment: `puclic`.......?

Answer (score 28):

Thats because you havent patched the `timer` method into the `Observable` prototype.

**Update: Rxjs 6.0.0**

Import the creation method as a static pure function:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
let timer$ = timer(2000,1000);
```

**Original answer:**

You have 2 options:

1) Patch the method with:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
```

2) Import the operator as a static pure function:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
let timer$ = timer(2000,1000);
```

Personally I would recommend the 2nd approach.

Comment: in rxjs 6.0 timer has moved: import { timer } from 'rxjs';

Comment: isn't the first one cause a Block-scoped Variable Issue?

Answer (score 4):

The timer function now need to be imported directly from **rxjs** library,
Below works fine.The message 'fired' will be seen in console after 10 seconds.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

const numbers = timer(10000);
numbers.subscribe(any => console.log('fired'));
```

Please see this link for more details:https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to **import** Observable from the root folder of library because older versions of rxjs does not provide complete Observable class in rxjs/Observable

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is a timer, you could use this too:

```
setInterval(() => {
      this.callNecessaryMethod();
    }, this.intervalInMilliSeconds);
```

This is the function prototype:

```
function setInterval(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timer (+2 overloads)
```

Comment: is it really? what is wrong with the `Observable.timer`?

Comment: @Tanmay P where do I write it? I wan to that When I clicked the button, start the timer?

Comment: Can I define multiple timers that call different functions using this way? @tanmay

Comment: @osmnfrkn61, yes you can define multiple timers that call different functions using this way.

Comment: @osmnfrkn61, its usage would be like:

function onButtonClick() {
      setInterval(() => {this.callNecessaryMethod();}, this.interval);
}