# Converting RxJS 5 Rx.Observable.timer(3000).mapTo({ id: 1 }) to RxJS 6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

How do we convert:

```
Rx.Observable.timer(3000).mapTo({ id: 1 })
```

to RxJS 6?

For example if we:

```
 import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
```

We still get:

> [ts] Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

All in all I'm trying to get this example [(From this tutorial)](https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0) to work:

```
    // Simulate HTTP requests 
    const getPostOne$ = Rx.Observable.timer(3000).mapTo({id: 1});
    const getPostTwo$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000).mapTo({id: 2});

    Rx.Observable.concat(getPostOne$, getPostTwo$).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47977979/1081909

Comment: Thanks - Got some of it worked out, but then concat no longer works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new way to do pipeable operators we no long user the `.` to chain observables but we use the pipe and pass in our operators separated by commas. Example in your scenario we would do

```
import { timer, concat } from 'rxjs'
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators'

  getPostOne$ = timer(3000).pipe(mapTo({ id: 1 }));
  getPostTwo$ = timer(1000).pipe(mapTo({ id: 2 }));

  concat(getPostOne$, getPostTwo$).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

You can read more about pipeable operators [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Hope this helps!